# autosys jil file: can I use update_job when adding a new attribute

Tags: autosys

I understand that in drafting a autosys jil file, I can use "update_job: job_name" to change the value of one or more job's attribute. For example:

```
update_job: abc_job
start_time: some_new_time
```

my question is, now I'd like to add a *new* attribute,

> run_calendar

to abc_job, can I just do:

```
update_job: abc_job
run_calendar: my_cal
```

I know I could have used a combine of:

```
delete_job: abc_job
insert_job: abc_job
```

with new attributes added, but since I have quite a few updates to do and each job has a certain size of body, I prefer to a more succinct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use update on your abc_job as follows:

```
update_job: abc_job
run_calendar: my_cal
```

However if you already used days_of_week you need to add that to your JIL as well so it would look like:

```
update_job: abc_job
run_calendar: my_cal
days_of_week:
```

Leaving the days_of_week empty.

Dave

Comment: I see. In my original jil file there is no days_of_week, then i guess I don't need to bother to add it, empty value or not. Thanks for the tip though, it could be useful some day.